# How I only use the storyboard no use the code to set the tableViewcell's height with autolayout?

Tags: ios

1. List item

   I want to set dynamics tableViewcell'height on the storyboard,not use the code With                              autolayout.
2. My English is poor.Thank you for answer this question. There are two labels on the tableViewCell's ContentView. The label's text is not limit length, and  Label'height is dynamic, the height is change by the data of the model. I want to set the UITableViewcell height is equal to the bigger label's height.

Comment: If it's dynamic, it's based on what? Content of the cell? In that case you probably needs to use code...

Comment: My English is poor.Thank you for answer this question. There are two labels on the tableViewCell's ContentView. The label's text is not limit length, and  Label'height is dynamic, the height is change by the date of the model. I want to set the UITableViewcell height is equal   the bigger label's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In iOS 8, Apple introduces a new feature for UITableView known as Self Sizing Cells

I don't have enough reputation to put picture here, but the tutorial below might help
http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: 感谢这个       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
                     tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you out...

In table view attribute Inspector make content as Dynamic Prototypes.

Comment: Thank you , I set the Dynamic Protoypes already. The height of the cell is same. How I set the height of cell with the cell Content View height in the storyboard .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to add constraints to cell..If yes then this is not possible...Although if you want to  cell height then select your tableView and set rowHeight in storyboard also make sure your prototype cell is of same height.

Comment: My English is poor.Thank you for answer this question. There are two labels on the tableViewCell's ContentView. The label's text is not limit length, and Label'height is dynamic, the height is change by the data of the model. I want to set the UITableViewcell height is equal to the bigger label's height